# How to get symfony 2 forms to return entities from a dynamic value

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

Ok here is a quick overview of what I am trying to do. I have a "Client" entity with a relationship to a "ClientDomain" entity. I need to have a form that will show me a list of all the ClientDomains for a given client. In the controller I know what client i need to filter for but im unsure how to pass that information to the formBuilder.

Heres what i have so far:

```
//src/NameSpace/ClientBundle/Entity/Client.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Client{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $client_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClientDomain", mappedBy="client")
 */
protected $domains;

...
}
```

And the form:

```
//src/LG/ClientBundle/Form/ClientDomainSelectionForm.php
namespace LG\ProjectBundle\Form\Projects;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ClientDomainSelectionForm extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('client_domain', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'LG\ClientBundle\Entity\ClientDomain',
            'query_builder'=> function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('cd')
                /* NEEDS TO FIND DOMAINS BY CLIENT X */
            },
            'property' => 'domain',
            'label' => 'Domain: '
        ));
    }
}
```

And then finally the controller:

```
//src/LG/ClientBundle/Controller/DomainSelectorController.php
namespace LG/ClientBundle/Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template; 

use LG\ClientBundle\Entity\Client;
use LG\ClientBundle\Entity\ClientDomain;
use LG\ClientBundle\Entity\ClientActiveDomain;
use LG\ClientBundle\Form\ClientDomainSelectionForm;


/**
 * @Route("")
 */
class DomainSelectorController extends Controller{

    /**
     * @Route("/client/{client_slug}/select-domain", name="lg.client.clientdomainselection.selectclient")
     * @Template
     */
    public function selectDomainAction(Request $request, Client $client){
        $activeDomain = new ClientActiveDomain();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ClientDomainSelectionForm(), $activeDomain );
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->bind($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($activeDomain );
                $em->flush();
                return $this->redirect(/*huge long url*/);
            }
        }
        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

}
```

As you can see I have access to the client entity in the controller im just not sure how to give that to the form builder so that it will only return domains for the current client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have found the answer, you just need to add a constructor to the form and pass in the client from the controller like so:

```
//src/LG/ClientBundle/Form/ClientDomainSelectionForm.php
namespace LG\ProjectBundle\Form\Projects;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ClientDomainSelectionForm extends AbstractType {

    protected $client;

    public function __construct(Client $client) {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $client = $this->client;
        $builder->add('client_domain', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'LG\ClientBundle\Entity\ClientDomain',
            'query_builder'=> function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) use ($client) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('cd')
                    ->where('cd.client = :client')
                    ->orderBy('cd.domain', 'ASC')
                    ->setParameter('client',$client->getClientId());
            },
            'property' => 'domain',
            'label' => 'Domain: '
        ));
    }
}
```

And Then in the controller:

```
//src/LG/ClientBundle/Controller/DomainSelectorController.php

...

public function selectDomainAction(Request $request, Client $client){

    ...

    $form = $this->createForm(new ClientDomainSelectionForm($client), $activeDomain );

    ...
}

...
```

Comment: Actually, you should create a required option `client` instead of using the constructor, because the constructor is called only once when creating the first instance of the form. So, if you had two forms with different clients, they would be bound to the client of the first form. On the other hand, options are not shared.

Comment: The client only needs to be set on create though. Once that is done all editing of the entity is possible because doctrine already knows about the client. But i can see where your use case could happen in another application. Thanks for the input.